# How to make multiple fields with taxonomy terms?

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

Like so: select-taxonomy-term - price - raiting

Like this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try field_collection.  Add one to your form, allowing multiple responses for the field.  Then add term reference, price, and rating fields to the field collection.

Comment: Thanks, i make that, it worked. But the is a problem. I have to add every item, by "add more", this is not convenient.

Comment: How do you want it to display?

Comment: Like in screenshot to see them all, at list to set some default values

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.  Does each row represent an existing term?

Comment: Yes, quite so ..

Comment: What should happen when you save the form?

Comment: Is is a part of anket material. Marked fields will save with the material and display to the users, with, or without price, and users may vote each of it